# PLS-00487 Error-Invalid reference to Variable 'CHAR'

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm designing a function that is part of a larger package. The function is intended to take a District Code and return a collection of unique IDs for 10-15 stores that are assigned to that district. The function is intended to return a collection that can be queried like a table, i.e., using the TABLE function in a SQL statement.

I've created the following Types:

Schema Level type:

```
create or replace TYPE HDT_CORE_ORGIDS AS TABLE OF CHAR(20);
```

and a Type inside the Package

```
TYPE CORE_ORGIDS IS TABLE OF CHAR(20) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Here's the function code:

```
     FUNCTION FindDistrictOrgs(
           ParamOrgCode VARCHAR2
      )
      RETURN HDT_CORE_ORGIDS
      AS
           ReturnOrgs HDT_CORE_ORGIDS := HDT_CORE_ORGIDS();
           FDOTemp HDT_CORE_MAIN.CORE_ORGIDS; 
           i BINARY_INTEGER := 0;

           CURSOR FDOCurr IS
                SELECT org.id AS OrgID
                     FROM tp2.tpt_company org
                     WHERE LEVEL = 2
                     START WITH org.name = ParamOrgCode
                     CONNECT BY PRIOR org.id = org.parent_id;

      BEGIN
           OPEN FDOCurr;
                LOOP
                     i := i +1;
                     FETCH FDOCurr INTO FDOTemp(i);
                     EXIT WHEN FDOCurr%NOTFOUND;
                END LOOP;
           IF FDOTemp.EXISTS(FDOTemp.FIRST) THEN
                ReturnOrgs.EXTEND(FDOTemp.LAST);
                FOR x IN FDOTemp.FIRST .. FDOTemp.LAST LOOP
                     ReturnOrgs(x) := FDOTemp(x).OrgID;
                END LOOP;
           END IF; 
           CLOSE FDOCurr;
           RETURN ReturnOrgs;         

 END FindDistrictOrgs ;
```

I'm getting the `PLS-00487:Invalid Reference to variable 'CHAR'` at the line:

```
                         ReturnOrgs(x) := FDOTemp(x).OrgID;
```

I've double-checked at the value returned by the SQL (the `org.id AS OrgID`) is of the `CHAR(20 BYTE)` datatype.

So...what's causing the error?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OrgID` is the alias you gave the column in your cursor, it has no meaning to the collection. Since both collections are of simple types you should just be doing:

```
ReturnOrgs(x) := FDOTemp(x);
```

The syntax you're using is implying `FDOTemp` is a collection of objects and you're trying to reference the `OrgID` attribute of an object; but since `CHAR` isn't an object type, this errors. The error message even makes some sense when viewed like that, though it's not terribly helpful if you don't already know what's wrong... and not entirely helpful when you do.

Incidentally, you could use a `bulk collect` to populate the collection without the cursor or loops, or the extra collection:

```
SELECT org.id
BULK COLLECT INTO ReturnOrgs
FROM tp2.tpt_company org
WHERE LEVEL = 2
START WITH org.name = ParamOrgCode
CONNECT BY PRIOR org.id = org.parent_id;
RETURN ReturnOrgs;
```

Comment: Sweet. This is spot on what I needed. :) And thanks for the BULK COLLECT hint. I'm still learning some PL/SQL tricks, so this is helpful. :)